# Change the color of the timeline in different states

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed a timeline with 4 levels. When I click on each of the levels, the timeline is filled with green color. Would it be possible to change this color in different types of states?

In state 4 I have the circle and the lines green, how can I change this color in the remaining 3?

That is, in 3 I want yellow color, in 2 green color 3 in 1 red color.

In the image, I leave an example of what I want

Can anyone help me?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline" >
    <li class="li" [ngClass]="priority['isComplete']?'complete':''" *ngFor="let priority of Priorities; let  p = index;">
        <div class="timestamp">
        </div>
        <div class="status">    
                <span class="circle" (click)="changeTimeline(priority.id)">{{priority.id}}</span>
            <h4 class="timelineh4">{{priority.text}}</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Component**

```
public Priorities:Array<Object> = [
    {id: 4, text: '',isComplete:true},
    {id: 3, text: '',isComplete:true},
    {id: 2, text: '',isComplete:true},
    {id: 1, text: '',isComplete:true},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change your method of calculate the selected level to save the selected state.

this `this.selectedPrioroties = prio;` will set the current state  and I have create a css classes base of the selected text

```
  public changeTimeline(prio) {
    this.selectedPrioroties = prio;
    this.selectedState =  String(prio.text).toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
  }
```

base of the `selectedState` `low , mid-low ,mid ,high` I create a set of classes in the css file `app.component.css`

```css
.circle {
    border: none;                 
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.low li:nth-child(1) .circle {
    background-color: #66DC71;    
}

.mid-low li:nth-child(1) .circle ,.mid-low li:nth-child(2) .circle {
    background-color: #ffeb3b;    
}

.mid li:nth-child(1) .circle ,.mid li:nth-child(2) .circle ,.mid li:nth-child(3) .circle {
    background-color: #2196f3;    
}
.high li:nth-child(1) .circle ,.high li:nth-child(2) .circle ,.high li:nth-child(3) .circle ,.high li:nth-child(4) .circle {
    background-color: #ff5722;    
}
```

*template*

```
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline" [ngClass]="selectedState" >
    <li class="li" *ngFor="let priority of Priorities; let  p = index;">
        <div class="timestamp">
        </div>
        <div class="status">    
                <span class="circle" (click)="changeTimeline(priority)">{{priority.id}}</span>
            <h4 class="timelineh4">{{priority.text}}</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6nrgdj)

Comment: if i want to put an asset by definition (can be 4) how should i proceed?

Comment: sorry , I don't get what you mean can you give more explanation 

Comment: Sorry :( As initial state I do not have any "circle" active. Is it possible to set the initial state to state 4? That is, when I open the application, the circle will be green (state 4). 
You can see this in the post image.

Comment: simply set the changeTimeline at ngOnInit , check I have update the demo